# Copying many named ranges using for loop

Tags: vba, loops, named-ranges

I am going to import some values from one workbook to another.

I want to do this by looping through the named ranges in the target workbook, and copy those named ranges in source workbook with exact similar name. The relevant names to be copied are listed in a worksheet called "Names" in the target workbook.

The actual named ranges are located in a worksheet called TargetSheet (I have given many single cells one name).

I know how to copy one named range from a workbook to another, when typing this, it works:

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TargetSheet").Range("TagName") = _
   Workbooks("Source").Sheets("SourceSheet").Range("TagName").

However, I don't manage to make a loop that copies values from all relevant named ranges, even if I include quotation marks in the string.

```
For i = 2 To 8
  For j = 1 To 6
    CurrentName = """" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Names").Cells(i, j) & """"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Target").Range(CurrentName) = _
      Workbooks("Source").Sheets("SourceSheet").Range(CurrentName)
  Next j
Next i
```

The code above gives error message 'Application defined or object defined error', while I hoped that some 42 cells would get updated values.

Comment: Where does it give the error message?

Comment: It gives error message on the line 'ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Target")...

Answer (score 0):

you should have a variable that brings the target table you want to update and then use
for example: 
`ra.CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("root_table")
re.CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("target_table")`

then handling all the code, update the target table doing:

`re.AddNew
 re.Update`

Comment: Thanks lot Elliott. I'm afraid I'm a novice in the world of VBA, so if you don't mind I'd like to ask a little more before I start digging into articles about openrecordset and databases.. 

I only have a table with the names of the named ranges. All cells that are to be updated are on the contrary spread all around in the target-sheet (as are the relevant source cells in the source sheet). Is that still ok with the approach you suggest, or should everything be organized in a table?

Comment: first as i see you are working on excel, i know more about access but here is a link that could help you to do what you want.. https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/copy-data-from-one-worksheet-to-another/ ` `

Answer (score 0):

`Method 2
Copy the data
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B10").Copy
Activate the destination worksheet
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Select the target range
Range("E1").Select
Paste in the target destination
ActiveSheet.Paste`

this could help you.. like i said im not xpert on excel.. but always there is a begining

Comment: Thank you very much Elliott, but I'm afraid this will not help this particular problem, since I want to copy some cells that are 'bookmarked' with a given name. Your solution works well if the system is 'static', but if a user adds or deletes rows the code will be outdated, therefore I need a method that handles named ranges... But I will investigate your tricks from Access and see if I can use it here!